# Search on WMPlayer Now Playing list

Tags: search, windows-media-player, music

I'm currently creating a playlist for a school play on Windows Media Player 12. It can at least consist of 200 short-length songs (1 minute at the least). **I just want to create a predetermined list of songs, nothing fancy, thus I simply want to do this on Windows Media Player rather than on another overly-complicated music players.**

The songs are already on the list (on the `Play Tab`), I'm just dragging songs up and down to arrange, and playing it at the same time to hear its effect. There are times that I need to search a particular song on the list but there is no search feature for the `Now Playing` list. I also tried to save that playlist and search on it using the `Search` field, but it either search directly on the library (rather than the `Now Playing` list) or show the message:

> *You are currently playing this list. You can edit it using the Play tab.*

If I remember correctly, there is a search feature for it on the previous versions since there is an entry for `Now Playing` on the left library tree. Is searching **directly** on `Now Playing` playlist possible or should I do it the long way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to search the contents of the `Play` tab. To make the `You are currently playing this list` message go away, simply start playing another playlist or a random song from your library. You can then select your playlist in the tree on the left, so that it appears in the Library pane, and use the `Search` field near the top.